# Div tag doesn't close in php

Tags: php, function, html, echo

Easy one! I'm trying to code a cheap forum. Coming from a C background, I started to noticed something strange about PHP. While having a function return a string (HTML) inside of a DIV into place, the browser would not print the `</DIV>` - even when it's echo'ed by itself.

Does PHP decide when it wants to echo certain DOM elements or have limitations on HTML output?

```
    echo "Start<div id='Forum'>";
    echo "Forum";   
    GetFullList();
    echo "</div>";
```

Where, GetFullList() consists of:

```
function GetFullList(){ 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `Forum` WHERE `IsReply` =0";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result){
            echo mysql_error();
        }
        if($result){
        while($ForumEntry = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $IsReply        =   $ForumEntry["IsReply"];
            $ParentPost =   $ForumEntry["ParentTopic"];
            $f_User     =   $ForumEntry["User"];
            $f_Replies      =   $ForumEntry["Replies"];
            $f_Views        =   $ForumEntry["Views"];
            $f_Time     =   $ForumEntry["Time"];
            $f_Post     =   $ForumEntry["Post"];
            $f_Topic        =   $ForumEntry["Topic"];
            $f_Index        =   $ForumEntry["Index"];
            echo DisplayPost($f_User, $f_Replies, $f_Views, $f_Time, $f_Post, $f_Topic, $f_Index);
            GetChildPostsOf($ParentPost);
                }
            }
        }
```

And DisplayPost() is built as such:

```
 function DisplayPost($f_User, $f_Replies, $f_Views, $f_Time, $f_Post, $f_Topic, $f_Index){           
            $PostBlock = "<div id='Grp_Cell' style='width:930;background-color:#999999;text-align:left;'><div id='Grp_Cell' style='float:left;'><div id='Tbl_Cel'>User: ".$f_User."</div><div id='Tbl_Cel'>Replies: ". $f_Replies."</div><div id='Tbl_Cel'>Views: ".$f_Views."</div><div id='Tbl_Cel'style='background-color:777777;height:112;'>Post started on ".$f_Time.".&nbsp;</div></div><div id='Grp_Cell' style='float:right;width:600;'><div id='Tbl_Cel'>Subject: ".$f_Topic."</div><div id='Tbl_Cel' style='background-color:777777;height:150;'>". $f_Post."</div><a onClick='Reply(".$f_Index.");Filter();'><div id='Tbl_Cel' style='background-color:#888888; height:50; width:50; float:right; padding:2;border-color:black; border:2;'><br>Reply</div></a></div>";
            return $PostBlock;
          }
```

(Displays a div scaffolding for DB results: the post.)
When I try to echo "< /div>" after GetFullList(), the result is not printed in HTML, leaving the rest of the page to be encompassed under the malformed div.

Comment: Return the string and echo getFullList(). There is likely an error in getchildpostof

Comment: Your $PostBlock has 10 opening divs and 9 closing divs.

Comment: @mplungjan I have. My point is that the last div might be echoed, but it's hard to tell since there will be so many divs that aren't closed. For instance, if DisplayPost is called 9 times, there will be 91 opening divs (9*10 + 1), and 82 closing divs (9*9 + 1).

Comment: @mplungjan actually he gave correct answer.

Comment: That is exceptionally fast... Scary. I'll check out aynber's solution first and will get back!

Comment: Ha! That did it! Thanks @aynber ! That string was one line, word-wrapped, jeez the eyestrain!

Comment: @user2690520 No problem. I actually had to break it into multiple lines just to see how that was set up.

Comment: How do I mark as answered?

Comment: Let me add it as an answer instead of a comment, and you can.

Comment: Sorry, I read, I have one /div too little, and then aynber said you have one /div too little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 10 opening divs and 9 closing divs in $PostBlock. A closing `</div>` should be added where necessary. An easy way to see what the output looks like is to break it into lines like this:

```
$PostBlock = "
<div id='Grp_Cell' style='width:930;background-color:#999999;text-align:left;'>         
    <div id='Grp_Cell' style='float:left;'>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel'>User: ".$f_User."</div>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel'>Replies: ". $f_Replies."</div>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel'>Views: ".$f_Views."</div>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel'style='background-color:777777;height:112;'>Post started on ".$f_Time.".&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id='Grp_Cell' style='float:right;width:600;'>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel'>Subject: ".$f_Topic."</div>
        <div id='Tbl_Cel' style='background-color:777777;height:150;'>". $f_Post."</div>
        <a onClick='Reply(".$f_Index.");Filter();'><div id='Tbl_Cel' style='background-color:#888888; height:50; width:50; float:right; padding:2;border-color:black; border:2;'><br>Reply</div></a>
    </div>  ";
```